# Set inclusion with $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ , $ \varepsilon $ , union and sum of absolute values

Tags: set-theory

First of all sorry for defining sets with square brackets instead of curly ones but this is my first time here and I struggled more than half an hour to write down it.

I have to prove this inclusion, which the texbook suggest to do by contradiction, but I don't know how to proceed.

$ \{ D \mid | f_n - f | + | g_n - g | \ge  \varepsilon \} \subset \{ D \mid | f_n - f |\ge  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \} \bigcup \{ D \mid | g_n - g | \ge  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \} $

Clearly this inclusion is quite intuitively since $\ge  \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ define a larger interval than $ \ge \varepsilon $

$ \{ D \mid | f_n - f | \ge  \varepsilon \} \subset \{ D \mid | f_n - f |\ge  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \} $

However, how can extend this type of argument using the union and $| f_n - f | + | g_n - g |$ ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Replace the absolute differences with just positive numbers, $a,b$. If $a+b\ge\epsilon$, you want to show *at least one of* $a$ or $b$ is $\ge\epsilon/2$.

Suppose that was not true. Then?

FWIW you can do curly braces with `\{12345\}`.